# Get value of a suggest button in messenger

Tags: c#, botframework, facebook-messenger

I've run in to some issues with suggest buttons in Facebook messenger. When i get the response from the user, i get the Title field back, and the value is lost. This works fine in the bot emulator, but not from Facebook messenger. Here is the code for creating the buttons:

```
        var reply = context.MakeMessage();
        reply.Text = "What can i do for you?";
        var suggests = new SuggestedActions();
        var actions = new List<CardAction>();
        foreach (var button in utter.Buttons)
        {
            actions.Add(new CardAction
            {
                Title = button.Text,
                Type = ActionTypes.ImBack,
                Value = button.Payload,
                Text = button.Payload,
                DisplayText = button.Text                    
            });
        }

        suggests.Actions = actions;
        reply.SuggestedActions = suggests;
        return reply;
```

When a user presses the button, i want the payload back to msbf, but i only get the button title. Could anyone please shed some light on what's happening here?

### Version

I'm using **Bot Builder** version `3.12.2.4`

Comment: Which version of the BotBuilder sdk are you using?

Comment: @EricDahlvang I updated the answer with BotBuilder version.

Comment: Please upgrade to the latest version

Comment: @EricDahlvang i did, the problem is still there. I found a workaround, see my answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to be a bug in the BotBuider SDK.
Adding

```
activity.Text = activity.GetChannelData<dynamic>()?.message?.quick_reply?.payload ?? activity.Text;
```

in MessagesController.cs resovles the issue.

Solution from this issue on github: https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/issues/3555